# Experimental proof of time-reversibility in microscopic classical physical laws

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, time, time-reversal-symmetry

All the laws of classical mechanics are time-reversible. But the experiments that we carry out on systems, mostly measure macroscopic parameters which are time-irreversible. We know for a reason that due to the loss of information from coarse-graining the microscopic laws, the macroscopic laws (of thermodynamics) are time-irreversible.

My question is, can we directly carry out experiments that can validate time-reversibility of classical mechanical laws (without involving measurement of macroscopic parameters)?

Secondly, if this is not possible, have there been attempts to make time-irreversible microscopic laws that describe all the other results that classical mechanics predict?

Comment: There have been experimental checks of Onsager reciprocity, which is equivalent to microscopic reversibility (detailed balace) and can be checked by measuring linear response functions.

Comment: @John Rennie : I was talking about the classical mechanical laws specifically.